# Concatenate two integers in Mathematica 7

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-7

What is the most efficient way to concatenate two positive integers in Mathematica 7?

`cc[123, 4567]` >> `1234567`

What about more than two?

`cc[123, 4, 567, 89]` >> `123456789`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will be slightly faster  for many integers, than your last solution:

```
ToExpression[StringJoin @@ Map[IntegerString, {##}]] &
```

A more concise alternative is to accept a single argument, assuming it to be a list, rather than a sequence, of numbers to concatenate:

```
ToExpression@StringJoin@IntegerString@#&
```

which is based on `IntegerString` being `Listable`.

Answer (score 3):

This only works properly for short integers because the output must be machine size, but it is the fastest I found:

```
Compile[{{a, _Integer}, {b, _Integer}}, 
  b + a 10^Floor[1 + Log[10, b]]
]
```

For longer integers, the fastest I could find is:

```
FromDigits[{##}, 10^IntegerLength@#2] &
```

For concatenating many integers, the following was faster than `Fold` on the one above:

```
FromDigits[Join @@ IntegerDigits[{##}]] &
```

Comment: In my timings the use of `IntegerLength[b]` in the compiled function is 20 times faster than the use of `Floor[...]` .

Comment: @Sjoerd, is that in version 8?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `Fold` is slow because it ends up multiplying small integers by large ones a lot for long arrays. You can get a factor of 2 speed up by using divide and conquer: `Clear[cc4];
cc4[{i_}] := i; cc4[{i1_, i2_}] := FromDigits[{i1, i2}, 10^IntegerLength[i2]]; cc4[x_List] := With[{k = Quotient[Length[x] + 1, 2]}, cc4[{cc4[Take[x, k]], cc4[Drop[x, k]]}] ]`.

Comment: @Mr.wizard V8, but I tried again and don't seem to be able to reproduce my timings. However, I did find an error in your first method: try `In[134]:= f[17211, 1000]` `Out[134]= 17212000`

Comment: It seems like a bug, but I guess it is a binary arithmetic problem.  `Floor@Log[10, 1000]` yields `2`.  `Chop` fixes it.

Comment: @Mr.wizard No, Floor@Log[10, 1000] yields 3. It's the +1 you added that causes the problem for 1000. This doesn't look like a job for Chop.

Comment: @Sjoerd, pardon me, you misunderstand.  Try:  `f[a_, b_] := b + a 10^Floor[1 + Log[10, b]]; f[17211, 1000]` --- the math is right.  Now try:  `Compile[{{b, _Integer}}, Floor@Log[10, b]][1000]` --- it yields 2. ;-)  You may be right about Chop.

Comment: ps. read "May be right about..." as "of course Chop doesn't do any good at all, what was I thinking!" ;-)

Comment: "The best minds make the best mistakes." Old Chinese proverb.