# Arrange & Display Parts of Grids in Mathematica

Tags: graphics, grid, wolfram-mathematica

In order to find quickly the location of my data, I display a table with my variables names as well as informations about each.

Since I have a lot of columns (variable) I copy and paste blocks of it in a cell to have them all on 1 screen.

I would like to code this, such that I would input several range of Rows to be extracted and efficiently displayed some how on a Grid that would fit an area of the screen ? I have failed yet to display 2 grid nicely together.

In case I did not express my problem properly above, here is a simple example:

How can I move the blue part to the side of the pink one if the output of `laList` is what we have to deal with ?

```
co1    = Range[6];
co2    = Range[11, 16];
co3    = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};

laList = Join[{co1}, {co2}, {co3}] // Transpose;

laListGraph = Grid[laList,
Dividers -> All,
Alignment -> {Left, Center},
ItemSize -> Automatic,
ItemStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 14, Black, Italic, Bold],
Spacings -> {2, 1},
 Background -> {None, None, {
     {{1, 3}, {1, 3}} -> LightRed,
     {{4, 6}, {1, 3}} -> LightBlue
   } } ]
```

Comment: Louis, unlike regular forums, there is no need to sign your posts with hi and bye and your name (because each post has your username under it). We're always on good terms, so the hi and bye are implied :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it.  Starting with your `laList` as defined in the question:

```
laList2 = ArrayFlatten @ {Partition[laList, 3]};

Grid[laList2,
Dividers -> All,
Alignment -> {Left, Center},
ItemSize -> Automatic,
ItemStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 14, Black, Italic, Bold],
Spacings -> {2, 1},
 Background -> {None, None, {
     {{1, 3}, {1, 3}} -> LightRed,
     {{1, 3}, {4, 6}} -> LightBlue
   } }
]
```

[image]

Please notice:

- the value `3` within `Partition` will need to be adjusted according to your list.
- the region specification for the `LightBlue` area was reversed.

---

A variation of yoda's code I like is:

```
subgrid= Grid[#1,
         Dividers  -> All,
         Alignment -> {Left, Center}, 
         ItemSize  -> Automatic, 
         ItemStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 14, Black, Italic, Bold], 
         Spacings  -> {2, 1}, 
         Background-> #2] &;

MapThread[subgrid, {Partition[laList, 3], {LightRed, LightBlue}}] //Row
```

Also, with this method you can partition a list that does not divide evenly:

```
MapThread[subgrid, {
  Partition[laList, 4, 4, 1, {}],
  {LightRed, LightBlue}
}] //Row
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

#### EDIT:

On second thoughts, what I had earlier is not what you wanted... you want it displayed as columns, but with the second half of the rows split and displayed beside the first. The following code should do that. Let me know if this is what you had in mind...

```
(Grid[#1, Dividers -> All, Alignment -> {Left, Center}, 
     ItemSize -> Automatic, 
     ItemStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 14, Black, Italic, Bold], 
     Spacings -> {2, 1}, 
     Background -> {None, 
       None, {{1, 3}, {1, 3}} -> #2}] &) @@@ {{laList[[;; 3, All]], 
    LightRed}, {laList[[4 ;;, All]], LightBlue}} // Row
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As I understood your question, the coloring was there just to show us which portion you want to "move up". So:

```
showG[l_List] :=
  Grid[Join[
    l[[ ;; IntegerPart[Length@l/2]]],
    l[[IntegerPart[Length@l/2] + 1 ;;]]
    , 2], Frame -> All];

showG[laList]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Or more to @Mr.'s taste:

```
showG[l_List] :=
  Grid[Join[l[[ ;; #]], l[[# + 1 ;;]], 2], Frame -> All] &@ Floor[Length@l/2];
```

Comment: I really had not considered that interpretation, but you may be right.  Remove the redundancy in your code and I'll +1 it.  Also, `Floor` is shorter than `IntegerPart`; is there a reason you use the latter?

Comment: @Mr. Many years ago I worked in an obscure language that used floating point representation for the `Floor` argument. There was a weird bug that _sometimes_ showed up producing (for integers) `Floor[n] == n-1`, and it kept me awake a few nights. Since then, I shiver each time I see `Floor[ ]`.

Comment: I think I ran into the same thing.  Please see the comments to this and tell me if it is so:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095959/concatenate-two-integers-in-mathematica-7/6095974#6095974

Comment: @Mr. Seems a similar issue, but mine happened many years before Mma materialization :D

Comment: Mathematica has me spoiled with arbitrary precision.  I couldn't figure out why I got that error until I remembered that it was impossible to represent the precise decimal integer in binary.